# can't create a table without foreign key errno:150 MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I had a table "supplier" that had foreign key constraints, dropped it and now i want to re-create that table with no foreign key at all, however i'm getting the classical error 150, any idea what can be done to re-create this table.

Comment: You'll need to post the `create` statements.

Answer (score 0):

In the file that the SQL is dumped in and that you are loading to recreate the database,
add `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0`;  at the start and `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS =` 1 at the end

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an inconsistency there, as creating a table without constraints should be possible at any time. From the [Mysql Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), what you should do is run

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS.
```

or

```
SHOW ERRORS
```

to check the detail of the error you are getting.